# Disabling automatic sorting in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, sorting

It seems Windows 10 automatically sorts files in an Explorer window with respect to some property. I want to disable automatic sorting to occur when I rename files. For Grouping files, I can select "None", but for sorting there is no such property.

Interestingly, sometimes sorting only happens when I press <kbd>F5</kbd>, which gives me the behavior I want, but I can't figure out why this is happening only sometimes.

Comment: @Akina: Please post a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting cannot be disabled, it can be altered only.

> sometimes sorting only happens when I press F5

It is strange that it is not performed after filesystem change - Explorer must check FS change events and rescan/resort.

Comment: Indeed, after working for a while in an Explorer window handling lots of files, sometimes the automatic sorting is disabled (I'm experiencing this now as I write this). Only pressing F5 will then sort files after renaming. Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: @Gruber I have seen that. Sometimes Explorer loose events. I don't know why.